# Select top one record for each unique value of column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I've this table structure

- request_id (F.K from some other table)
- user_id
- price

I want top one record order by price but for each unique value of request_id, for example say if I've

```
request_id  user_id price
       1,       1,  100
       1,       2,  200
       1,       3,  300                     
       2,       2,  10
       2,       1,  20
       2,       3,  30
```

Then the desired result would be:

```
request_id  user_id price
       1,       1,  100
       2,       2,  10
```

SELECT user_id,price FROM request ORDER BY price LIMIT 1

Comment: Please re-format your data and the desired output in a table form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT request_id,MIN(price) min_price FROM my_table GROUP BY request_id )y
    ON y.request_id = x.request_id
   AND y.min_price = x.price;
```